# Nexus 7 2013 - stuck at android is starting optimizing apps. trying adb to get the data

Tags: adb, boot-loop, nexus-7

I have a 2013 model Nexus 7.
It is running 6.0.1, unmodified with locked bootloader. USB debugging is on.

Battery drained to 0. Charged then the device is stuck on boot loop .. android is optimizing app X of x.
I don't wanna lose the data so I've avoided hard reset.

- I've wiped cache more than once.
- I tried ADB Commands .. and while on the android is starting I can list the device and I can list the directoies ..
- Tried adb pull /
  and it return this message.

  > c:\Adb>adb pull /
  >
  > - daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
  > - daemon started successfully adb: warning: stat failed for path /proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/self/task/1208/root/proc/222/task/1208/fd/15:
  >   Protocol not available

**Tried shell to see if I can list folders and**

```
Adb shell ls /sdcard/sdcard
it returns the same message.

c:\Adb>adb shell ls /mnt

asec

expand

media_rw

obb

runtime

sdcard *******************

secure

user

c:\Adb>adb shell ls /mnt/sdcard/
/mnt/sdcard/: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way that I can retrieve the data before hard resetting .. through adb or custom recovery .. or whatever.

Comment: @alecxs 
The first command returns this >> 
`adb: error: remote object '/storage/emulated/0' does not exist`

Comment: @alecxs 
Second command returns this when trying to access the expand folder >> `opendir failed, Permission denied`

Comment: *'adb shell "find /mnt /storage 2> /dev/null" > index.txt'* will give you list of available files you can pull

Comment: @alecxs I successfully pushed a file .. `c:\Adb>adb push H.txt /data/local/tmp
H.txt: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 0.0 MB/s (13 bytes in 0.000s)`

Comment: it might be */sdcard* is protected with screen lock. try to gather some info from [logcat](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logcat/info) maybe you figure out reason. if some app causes this you should be able to disable that app from package manager (pm). worth mention on factory reset you will lose MicroSD Card content too. maybe [nvflash](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1745450) is of any help

Comment: I couldn't get the second command to give me a text file .. but running the command without the index.txt part. returns this. /mnt
/mnt/sdcard
/mnt/runtime
/mnt/expand

Comment: try again with *'find -L /mnt /storage 2> /dev/null'* if still no result guess your files aren't accessable until screen will unlocked. therefore logcat is the way to figure out/fix

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3484879 try dirty cow exploit to get root shell. also this root method claims it is working from stock revovery without data loss (no mention of bootloader state) https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3219148

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119980/discussion-between-corabict-and-alecxs).